# Connection Reset by Peer: Socket Write Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, jdbc, connectivity

We have a vendor working on Java (JDBC) application saying they are getting the error

> Connection Reset by Peer: Socket Write Error

They are insisting that the SQL Server (SQL Server 2012) is forcibly disconnecting their application server for some reason. I have run Profiler traces to collect Attention and User Error Message events and have found nothing helpful. I have checked the ring buffer and have only failed logins - no disconnects.

```
SELECT CAST(record AS XML) FROM sys.dm_os_ring_buffers
WHERE ring_buffer_type = 'RING_BUFFER_CONNECTIVITY'
```

Windows logs do not show anything helpful. Is this an error I should be able to track down in SQL Server, or is this purely a network error that will need a network trace or something else? Any ideas?

Comment: In SQL Server 2012 you should check the `system_health` session as it has most of the security ring buffer events. As well, a failed login can also be considered a disconnect.

Comment: I've seen this happen when I wanted to write a file on a SAMBA drive, and it turned out that the network card was overloaded.
When I tried copying large files across the network these failed too, when using COPY and/or Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't look like an issue with SQL Server. Here's a link which talks about connection being forcibly closed by sql server :

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187005(v=sql.105).aspx

Also, the following post might help you analyze the error further :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611741/java-net-socketexception-connection-reset-by-peer-socket-write-error-when-serv

Comment: Agreed, a socket write error could be the SQL Server OS/Machine having an issue on the network side, but I doubt this would be related to the SQL Server processes unless it was under some extreme conditions.